# How do I make a function with a parameter depending on a type from a Type Provider?

Tags: f#, type-inference, type-providers, type-constraints

I'm quite new to F#.

I'm trying to create a base utility function that depends on a type which uses a Type Provider:

```ml
open FSharp.Text.RegexProvider

type DotnetVersionRegex = Regex< @"dotnet (?<Version>.*)" >
type OutlookVersionRegex = Regex< @"Outlook (?<Version>.*)" >

let parseOptionalValue matcher values =
    values
    |> Seq.map (fun x -> matcher x)
    |> Seq.tryFind (fun x ->
        (^T : (member Success: bool) x) && (^T : (member Version: System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group) x).Success) // x.Success && x.Version.Success
    |> function
        | Some m -> Some ((^T : (member Version: System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group) m).Value) // m.Version.Value
        | None -> None

// The first time I use "parseOptionalValue" it produces a warning "This construct causes code to be less generic...
// […] the type variable 'T has been constrained to be type 'Regex<...>.MatchType'.
let dotnetVersion = parseOptionalValue (DotnetVersionRegex().TypedMatch)

// The second time I use "parseOptionalValue",
// it produces an error "This expression was expected to have type
// <the type of the parameter passed in the first use just above (DotnetVersionRegex().TypedMatch),
//     that is, the Regex type provider with the pattern of my first regex>"
let outlookVersion = parseOptionalValue (OutlookVersionRegex().TypedMatch)
```

For reference, because it might be more legible, here is what I'm trying to avoid:

```ml
let dotnetVersion values =
    values
    |> Seq.map (fun x -> DotnetVersionRegex().TypedMatch x)
    |> Seq.tryFind (fun x -> x.Success && x.Version.Success)
    |> function
        | Some m -> Some m.Version.Value
        | None -> None
let outlookVersion values =
    values
    |> Seq.map (fun x -> OutlookVersionRegex().TypedMatch x)
    |> Seq.tryFind (fun x -> x.Success && x.Version.Success)
    |> function
        | Some m -> Some m.Version.Value
        | None -> None
```

Questions:

- Is my code looking like something correct and missing something (what?), or am I going in the wrong direction?
- More generally speaking, how can I create a function with a parameter depending on a type from a Type Provider? Is it possible without losing type safety?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
let parseOptionalValue<'T when 'T :> System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match> (matcher:string->'T) (values:string seq) : 'T option =
    values
    |> Seq.map (fun x -> (matcher x))
    |> Seq.tryFind (fun x -> x.Success)

let inline v (x:^T) = (^T : (member Version : System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group) x)

let inline parseVersion matcher values =  parseOptionalValue matcher values
                                          |>Option.bind (fun x->let group = v x  
                                                                if group.Success then Some group.Value
                                                                else
                                                                None)

let v1 = parseVersion (DotnetVersionRegex().TypedMatch) [ "dotnet 3.5" ]

let v2 = parseVersion (OutlookVersionRegex().TypedMatch) [ "Outlook 3.5" ]


match v1 with
| Some(v) -> printfn "version %s" v
| None -> printfn "none"
```

Outputs:

```
version 3.5
```

On a side note this is overkill if this is your real scenario as you'd create a single Version regex

```
type VersionRegex = Regex< @"(?<Product>\\w+)(?<Version>.*)" >
```

Comment: But didn't you just elude the problem by not using the "Version" property?

Is it actually possible to make a generic function that is aware the result should have a "Version" property, regardless of the actual type, and use it?

Comment: @Melvyn that's not possible as there are no relation between the two types

Comment: They both have a member of the same name returning a value of the same type. Isn't it what duck typing is all about?

Comment: Thank you anyway for your answer. It made me google harder :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way to make it work: it compiles when I add the `inline` keyword to my `parseOptionalValue` function!

I honestly don't understand very well the reason it wasn't compiling in the first place and the exact role of the `inline` keyword...

I also still have a faint hope there is a better way to write a strongly typed version of my initial example, so feel free to suggest other answers...

Here is the cleaned up and working version:

```ml
open FSharp.Text.RegexProvider

type DotnetVersionRegex = Regex< @"dotnet (?<Version>.*)" >
type OutlookVersionRegex = Regex< @"Outlook (?<Version>.*)" >

let inline parseOptionalValue matcher values =
    values
    |> Seq.map (fun x -> matcher x)
    |> Seq.tryFind (fun x ->
        (^T : (member Success: bool) x) && (^T : (member Version: System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group) x).Success) // x.Success && x.Version.Success
    |> function
        | Some m -> Some ((^T : (member Version: System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group) m).Value) // m.Version.Value
        | None -> None

let dotnetVersion (values: string array) = parseOptionalValue (DotnetVersionRegex().TypedMatch) values
let outlookVersion (values: string array) = parseOptionalValue (OutlookVersionRegex().TypedMatch) values

let printSome = function
    | Some x -> printfn "%O" x
    | None -> printfn "None"

let values = "dotnet 4.5;Outlook 16".Split(';')
dotnetVersion values |> printSome
outlookVersion values |> printSome
```